# Issue in loopback's upsertWithWhere()

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using **loopback3.x**. Why upsertWithWhere function always updates the same instance? Only one instance is there for all the time when updateWithWhere function executes.

```js
app.models.oneTimePassword.upsertWithWhere({
    where: {
        userId: user.id
    }
}, {
    userId: user.id,
    otp: otp,
    updatedAt: updatedAt,
    type: 'email'
}, (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
        callback(null, {
            status: "OK",
            message: "email sent"
        });
    } else {
        callback(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.models.oneTimePassword.upsertWithWhere(
  {
    userId: user.id
  },
  {
    userId: user.id,
    otp: otp,
    updatedAt: updatedAt,
    type: 'email'
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
        callback(null, {
            status: "OK",
            message: "email sent"
        });
    } else {
        callback(err);
   });
```

Try this, The first argument of `upsertWithWhere` should be `where` therefore, you don't need to add `where: {}` check out this official [documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-upsertwithwhere)